# Adaptive Background Subtraction to Obtain silhouettes

Tags: matlab, background-subtraction

The following piece of code for background subtraction in videos does not work well with a video with vivid/adaptive background.(shows good result for some videos with steady/plain background) I get patched outputs rather than a silhouette.
I am working on videos where I need to extract silhouettes of "two humans at a time"(as the foreground)
Here is the code and the corresponding output,

```
 fontSize = 14;
 obj = VideoReader('sample.avi');

 for f=1:frames              
 I=read(obj,f);   
 figure(1);
 imshow(I);
 title('Input Video Sequence'); 
 caption = sprintf('Frame%4d',f);
 title(caption, 'FontSize', fontSize);
 if f==1    
     Background=I;    
     Fg=abs(I-Background);
 else
     %Background=(1-alpha)* f + alpha * Background;
     Fg=abs(I-Background); 

 end
 grayImage = rgb2gray(abs(im2double(Fg))); % Convert to gray level
 thresholdLevel = graythresh(grayImage);
 binaryImage = im2bw(grayImage,thresholdLevel);
 figure(2);
 imshow(binaryImage);
 drawnow;
 pause(0.2)
 end
```

Corresponding Output for a video which contains two humans,

[Original Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HihNV.png)

[Obtained Foreground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9ovk.jpg)

Any Help would be Appreciated! and thanks :)

Comment: Start this kind of question on Google, you will get much better results; once you know what you are doing and have difficulties, then post your specific programming related questions here.

Comment: I hope now I'm more clear @GameOfThrows :)